# Horizontal scrolling is not working as intended

Tags: tailwind-css

I have setup this playground to show the problem I am having

[tailwind playground example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/RXxYGvwfum)

Resize the window a little to get the scroll bar.

I want to have scrolling just in the body element of this layout.

When scrolling is activated, it hides parts of some elements, and I can't get them fully visible when scrolling.
What am I missing here ?

Comment: It because of `justify-center`. If you remove it, you'll be able to see whole elements. I'm not entirely sure what desired result (design) is but keep in mind this flex behavior

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka thank you ! it worked, it's supposed to be a seating layout design. now that `justify-center` got out, is there any way to keep this centered ?

Comment: You may set fixed parent width instead of screen. This way you will ensure it doesn\`t get squeezed. In your case it would be `11*48px + 10*8px = 608px (38rem)`, so change `w-screen` with `w-[38rem] mx-auto`

Comment: also you may achieve same [result](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cZbPbX5R4D?size=734x727) with CSS Grid, which is much cleaner in my opinion

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka , if you provide an answer i can mark it that as Accepted Answer )